# Formula applied to new row

Tags: google-sheets

If I have a formula (of any kind) spanning `A1:A30` (just as an example), when I right click and insert a new row, it doesn't have the same formula.

Numbers (and I believe Excel) allows this, is there a way to obtain this behavior in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want may be an array formula. Say B1:B4 contains 1,2,3,4 respectively, and the formula in A1 is:

```
=ArrayFormula(B1:B^2)
```

A1:A4 should show 1,4,9,16 respectively.

Select Row3 and Insert 1 above. The results in A1:A5 should now be 1,4,0,9,16 respectively.

Enter say `10` in B3 and the `0` in A3 should change to `100`.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of just inserting a row, you select a row, copy it and then Insert copied cells it should duplicate your formulas